# Por qué me sale " Call to undefined function mysqli_quey() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel\reservar.php on line 13"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Aquí está mi código:

```
<?php
        include ('Conexion.php');

            $cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
            $personas=$_POST['cper'];
            $dias=$_POST['cdias'];
            $numhab=$_POST['numb'];
            $fecin=$_POST['fecini'];
            $fecfin=$_POST['fecfin'];


                    $query="SELECT * FROM persona WHERE per_cedula='$cedula'";
                    $result=mysqli_quey($conexion,$query);

                    if($result){
                            $sql="INSERT INTO `reserva` (`per_id`,`res_personas`,`res_dias`,`res_estado`,`res_numero`,`res_fecin`,`res_fecfin`) VALUES ('".$result['per_id']."','$personas','$dias','Ocupado','$numhab','$fecin','$fecfin')";
                            $resultado=$conexion->query($sql);
                            echo "<script>alert('Registro Exitoso');</script>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<script>alert('Error al ingresar los datos')</script>".mysqli_connect_error();
                        }

       header('location:reservas.php');

    ?>
```

Comment: Tienes un error tipografico es `mysqli_query` te falta una `r` en `mysqli_quey`. Voto para cerrar/eliminar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está claro, se te esta indicado que has nombrado mal la función debido a que `mysqli_quey` no  existe o esta declarada, no coincide con `mysqli_query` que es la función por defecto.

Cuando el IDE busca ese nombre, no lo encuentra y por eso el error.

En resumen: **Call to undefined function mysqli_quey()** es en español **Llamada a la función NO DEFINIDA mysqli_quey()**

Reemplaza esto:

```
$result=mysqli_quey($conexion,$query);
```

Por esto:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que es porque esta mal escrito, ya que es: mysqli_query()